# Нужна ли запятая в составном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:

«Без своевременного лечения, кариес приводит к осложнениям».

Спасибо вам за разъяснения и всего доброго.

Александр.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Нужна ли запятая в составном предложении?
```

А что такое **составное предложение**? Не знаю такого термина. Это простое двусоставное неосложнённое предложение.

*Без своевременного лечения кариес приводит к осложнениям.*

Причин для обособления сочетания *Без своевременного лечения* не вижу - это  не оборот, не вводное сочетание, не пояснение. Зачем его выделять запятыми?

Comment: Ясно! Людмила, спасибо вам за ответ.